# Wordpress | Facebook share gives 404 error

Tags: wordpress, facebook, http-status-code-404

When I want to share a page on my wordpress website I get a *404 error*.
I did put my website through the facebook debugger this was the result.

[Facebook Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xcpn.png)

The IP adress is also not right, how do i change that?

Answer (score 0):

That’s an IPv6 address shown there.

Facebook prefers IPv6 over v4 when available. This sometimes causes problems like this, when the DNS settings for the domain are wrong. Most users still use IPv4, so the problem doesn’t become visible until such a client that perfers v6 comes along.

Check the DNS settings for the domain (or ask your server admin to do it), looks like the AAAA record for the IPv6 address is wrong.